# How to effectively compute fundamental units in rings?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, algebraic-number-theory

Consider the ring of integers of $K=\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt 2,\sqrt 3)$. By Dirichlet's unit theorem the units of $\mathcal O_K$ have rank 3, so they are expressible as $\pm u_1^au_2^bu_3^c$ for suitable units $u_1,u_2,u_3$ and $a,b,c\in\mathbb Z$. I found three units which are not expressible as powers of each other: $1+\sqrt 2$, $2+\sqrt 3$ and $\sqrt 3+\sqrt 2$ but how do I guarantee that none of these units is a power of another unit i.e $u^n=1+\sqrt 2$ or the same for the other two? For fields of the form $\mathbb Q(\sqrt m, \sqrt n)$ for coprime squarefree positive integers $m,n$ is it always sufficient to examine the minimal nontrivial solutions to $x^2-my^2=\pm 1$, $x^2-ny^2=\pm 1$ and $x^2-mny^2=\pm 1$?

Comment: I know the papers of M. Pohst for the effective computation of fundamental units in general, e.g., see [here](http://www.ams.org/journals/mcom/1982-38-157/S0025-5718-1982-0637307-6/S0025-5718-1982-0637307-6.pdf). For real biquadratic number fields this should simplify; perhaps this is already done somewhere. I found more explicit examples [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/165506/unit-group-of-biquadratic-fields). Have you see the thesis of [N. Jeans](https://mro.massey.ac.nz/bitstream/handle/10179/4630/02_whole.pdf?sequence=1)?

Comment: You can  search for $3$ units $u_1,u_2,u_2$ with $U_j = \log(\sigma_1(u_j),\ldots,\log\sigma_4(u_j))$ linearly independent and check if $\det(U)$ matches the regulator [obtained](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Class_number_formula) from $\zeta_K$.