# What are the units in $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2}, \sqrt{3})$?

Tags: ring-theory, algebraic-number-theory, diophantine-equations

I'd like to find the four independent units in (the ring of integers of ) $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2}, \sqrt{3}) \subseteq \mathbb{R}$ We also have that $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2}, \sqrt{3}) \simeq \mathbb{Q}[x,y]/(x^2 - 2, y^2 - 3)$, as a [field extension](http://www.jmilne.org/math/CourseNotes/FT.pdf).

---

I just want to find the Norm, $\mathfrak{N}(x)$ for $x = a + b \sqrt{2} + c \sqrt{3} + d\sqrt{6} \in \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2}, \sqrt{3})$.  The conjugates are like this:

$$ \big(a + b \sqrt{2} + c \sqrt{3} + d\sqrt{6}\big) 
\big(a - b \sqrt{2} + c \sqrt{3} - d\sqrt{6}\big)
\big(a + b \sqrt{2} - c \sqrt{3} - d\sqrt{6}\big)
\big(a - b \sqrt{2} - c \sqrt{3} + d\sqrt{6}\big)$$

If we multiply all four of these things together, we obtain a mess.  I used [sympy](http://docs.sympy.org/latest/tutorial/simplification.html#polynomial-rational-function-simplification):
$$
a^4 - 4\,a^2b^2 - 6\,a^2c^2 - 12\,a^2d^2 + 48\,abcd + 4\,b^4 - 12\,b^2c^2 - 24\,b^2d^2 + 9\,c^4 - 36\,c^2d^2 + 36\,d^4
$$
Instead we can rearrange the terms it looks almost manageable:
$$ (a^4 + 4\,b^4 + 9\,c^4 + 36\,d^4)- (4\,a^2 b^2 + 6 \, a^2 c^2 + 12\,a^2 d^2 + 12\,b^2c^2 + 24\,b^2 d^2 + 36\, c^2 d^2 ) + (48\, abcd)$$
and [Dirichlet's Unit theorem](http://www.math.uconn.edu/~kconrad/blurbs/gradnumthy/unittheorem.pdf) says we can find integers $a,b,c,d \in \mathbb{Z}$ such that this thing $=1$.

---

Fortunately, I can find two subfields off the bat:  $[\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2}, \sqrt{3}): \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2})] = 2$ and $[\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2}, \sqrt{3}): \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{3})] = 2$ and we get that :

$$ 1, 3 + 2\sqrt{2}, 2 + \sqrt{3} \in \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2}, \sqrt{3}) $$
are still units in this quartic field (by [Pell Eq](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pell%27s_equation)).  **There's one left.  Which is it?**

---

Related:

- [Is $\mathbf{Q}(\sqrt{2}, \sqrt{3}) = \mathbf{Q}(\sqrt{2}+\sqrt{3})$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/93463/is-mathbfq-sqrt2-sqrt3-mathbfq-sqrt2-sqrt3?noredirect=1&lq=1)

Comment: The notation $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2},\sqrt{3})$ denotes the _field_ over $\mathbb{Q}$ generated by the set $\{\sqrt{2},\sqrt{3}\}$. But you want the ring, not the field, so the correct notation is $\mathbb{Q}[\sqrt{2},\sqrt{3}]$.

Comment: $(1+\sqrt{2})$ is a fundamental unit of $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2})$ (of norm $-1$, that's OK). There are three fundamental units.

Comment: @quasi, but the two notations denote in this case the same thing.

Comment: You don't really want the units in $Q(\sqrt2,\sqrt3)$ but in its ring of integers, probably, and a good start would be finding that ring!

Comment: @Mariano Suárez-Álvarez:: Right, so the OP presumably wants $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{2},\sqrt{3}]$ (and still square brackets).

Comment: Related:https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2525180/how-to-effectively-compute-fundamental-units-in-rings   https://mathoverflow.net/questions/165506/unit-group-of-biquadratic-fields

Comment: See [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1712116/11619) for three independent units (not sure about the full unit group IIRC).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just a check that Pell unit provided by @Rene Schipperus is indeed independent of the other Pell units. For assume that we have 
$$(3+2\sqrt{2})^m(2+\sqrt{3})^n(5+2\sqrt{6})^p=1$$
Applying the Galois maps $\sqrt{2}\mapsto - \sqrt{2}$ ,$\sqrt{3}\mapsto - \sqrt{3}$  we get 
$$(3-2\sqrt{2})^m(2-\sqrt{3})^n(5+2\sqrt{6})^p=1$$
so 
$$(3+2\sqrt{2})^m(2+\sqrt{3})^n=(3-2\sqrt{2})^m(2-\sqrt{3})^n$$
and therefore
$$\left(\frac{3+2\sqrt{2}}{3-2\sqrt{2}}\right) ^m=\left(\frac{2-\sqrt{3}}{2+\sqrt{3}}\right)^n$$
so both must be in $\mathbb{Q}$, since $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2})\cap \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{3})=\mathbb{Q}$. Now, from $\left(\frac{3+2\sqrt{2}}{3-2\sqrt{2}}\right) ^m \in \mathbb{Q}$, applying the Galois map $\sqrt{2}\mapsto -\sqrt{2}$ we conclude that 
$$\left(\frac{3+2\sqrt{2}}{3-2\sqrt{2}}\right) ^m=\left(\frac{3-2\sqrt{2}}{3+2\sqrt{2}}\right) ^m$$ 
so the common value must be $\pm 1$. We conclude that $m=0$. Similarly we get $n=0$.

ADDED: Using  WolframAlpha I got [this result](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=NumberFieldsFundamentalUnits%5BSqrt%5B2%5D%2BSqrt%5B3%5D%5D). The surprise was
$$2+\sqrt{3}=\left(\frac{\sqrt{2}+\sqrt{6}}{2}\right )^2$$
Moreover, the units 
$$1+\sqrt{2}, \frac{\sqrt{2}+\sqrt{6}}{2}, \sqrt{2}+\sqrt{3}$$
form a fundamental system.

Note that $\frac{\sqrt{2}+\sqrt{6}}{2}=\frac{1+\sqrt{3}}{\sqrt{2}}$

Comment: After thinking about it for a while, I realize we're *still* not done since there could another generator $x \in \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2}, \sqrt{3})$ such that $\langle 5 + 2 \sqrt{6} \rangle \subseteq \langle x \rangle$.  The notes have $x = \frac{\sqrt{2} + \sqrt{6}}{2}$ but a derivation could be nice.

Comment: @cactus314:  Indeed, $5+2\sqrt{6} = (\sqrt{2}+\sqrt{3})^2$.  So the three units $1+\sqrt{2}$, $2+\sqrt{3}$, $\sqrt{2}+\sqrt{3}$ generate a subgroup of finite index inside the group of units. The question is whether this index is $1$ or not.

Comment: @cactus314: please check the added stuff in the answer.

Comment: @Jyrki Lahtonen: Yes, thank you!  I am still impressed with WolframAlpha.

Answer (score 1):

The fundamental unit of $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{6})$ is $$5+2\sqrt{6}$$ Does this help ?

Comment: I think so... I can't rule out that $5 + 2 \sqrt{6} \in \langle 3 + 2 \sqrt{2}, 2 + \sqrt{3}\rangle$.